# Fourier coefficients (full-range series)

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

For the periodic function $f(\theta)=(\theta^2-\pi^2)^2$ on the interval $-\pi\leq\theta<\pi$, show that it has the Fourier series $$f(\theta)=\frac{8\pi^4}{15}+24\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^4}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}n\theta}.$$
My attempt:
The general formula for the Fourier coefficients $a_n$ for a periodic function $f(\theta)$ with period $T$ is given by: $a_n=\frac1T\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}n\theta}d\theta $. In this case, $T=2\pi$ (because the function is periodic on the interval). Then:
$$\begin{aligned}a_n&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\theta^2-\pi^2)^2\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}n\theta}d\theta\\\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\theta^2-\pi^2)^2\cos(n\theta)+\mathrm{i}(\theta^2-\pi^2)^2\sin(n\theta)d\theta\end{aligned}$$
I am not sure how to progress futher. Can someone help in finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. Expand $(\theta^2 - \pi^2)^2$.
2. Evaluate $\int x^n e^{ax} dx$.